# NULL character is passed to Oracle procedure by 64-bit C++ application

Tags: c++, sql, string, oracle, stored-procedures

I am converting my C++ application to 64-bit. The problem I am having has to do with Oracle calls. Any string (varchar2) parameter I pass to an Oracle procedure has a null character at the end. For example:

```
ProductionDB * pxDB = DBPool::pxGetDB();
pxDB->vResetParams();
pxDB->vSetProc(PROCNAME, 1);
pxDB->vSetInputParam(1, SQL_CHAR, “FIRST_NAME_SOUNDEX”);
pxDB->vExecuteProc();
```

In the example above, after debugging the Oracle procedure, I see that FIRST_NAME_SOUNDEX has a “\0” (NULL) character appended at the end. So, if I am trying to insert something in the database, I get a reject message that the value is too large for the column. This works with the 32-bit version of the application and 32-bit Oracle driver. Currently, I am using 64-bit version of the application (compiled in VS2010) and 64-bit Oracle driver 11.02.00.01. I have also tried the new driver 12.01.00.01, but it didn’t help.

Comment: I've never used OCI, but `\0` is the string terminator for old-style  C strings. Are you sure that character is the problem? Is the character present in the 32bit version?

Comment: The character was never present in the 32bit version of the application. It has been working fine for 10 years. Now, it is useless because every call to Oracle that passes a string (varchar2) has an extra character "\0" at the end. We are talking about hundreds of Oracle procedures, so modifying them would not be a viable option.